# c# .net BundleConfig adding custom css dir/files

Tags: c#, .net

I am running VS2017.  In my simple project I have the standard `Content` dir.  I added an `index.css` file in there to hold custom css.  I setup my `BundleConfig` as:

```
...
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/local").Include(
        "~/Content/index.css"
    )
);
...
```

I modified the `_Layout.cshtml` file with:

```
...
@Styles.Render("~/Content/local")
...
```

and everything was fine.  I then realized i would have at least one more custom css file so I added a new dir named `local` under `Content`; moved the `index.css file` in there and adjusted the `BundleConfig` as:

```
...
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/local").Include(
        "~/Content/local/index.css"
    )
);
...
```

and the web browser would not load the css.  I have since renamed the folder `localCss` and have modified the `BundleConfig` and layout to reflect the change.

```
...
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/localCss").Include(
        "~/Content/index.css"
    )
);
...
```

and things work again.

This is odd to me because I did the same basic thing with local javascript files and that works just fine as:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/local").Include(
        "~/Scripts/local/index.js",
        "~/Scripts/local/popups.js"
    )
);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Your bundle name should be different from physical folder path otherwise it wont create bundle.

Comment: Doh! thanks. I only just saw how differently the script and content bundles were named.